# EMM agent not updating polling frequency

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

Ime currently using EMM v 2.0.1 but having an issue updating the polling interval.

I have updated the Android and general poling via the APIs but some phones are stil polling 3 times a sec. We have 1900 devices enrolled and this adding a dent in the data budget.

When the device is enrolled a polling frequency is set as part of the enrollment process. Can this be updated after the device is enrolled, because ime seeing devices are using the polling that was set on registration and not the updated value.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug. This will be fixed soon in the next release. I have raised a [Jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-1630) to track it.

As a workaround you can do it by changing the source of emm-agent-android to update the polling interval automatically (By getting it from the server). or you can set the default polling interval in emm-agent manually.

Hope this helps.